# SELECT table with LEFT JOIN in where clause result

Tags: mysql, sql

Below query return : #1054 - Unknown column 'word.id' in 'where clause'

```
select * from word,(
SELECT sqrt(variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)))/avg(ifnull(re_freq,0)) cv
FROM pre_cat 
left join (select * from goal where wordid= word.id)g on pre_cat.id= g.catid) gg
```

How can I fix it?

below query return correct result but just for one record!

```
SELECT  avg(ifnull(re_freq,0)) , variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)),sqrt(variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)))/avg(ifnull(re_freq,0))
FROM pre_cat 
left join (select * from goal where wordid= 9690)g on pre_cat.id= g.catid
```

and crrect result of this query is: 0.500000000375
Upldated schema SQL fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de6c0/2

How cant I do it for All result?
Please help me!

below stored procedure work correctly, but takes too long!

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE wo_id INT;
    DECLARE num INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE res DOUBLE;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM word INTO num;
    SET i=0;
    WHILE i<num DO 
        SELECT  sqrt(variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)))/avg(ifnull(re_freq,0)) FROM pre_cat left join (select * from goal where wordid= i )g on pre_cat.id= g.catid INTO res;
        update word set cv=res where id=i;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: You can not reference to outer table in a inner sql.

Comment: Your syntax for JOIN is incorrect. Explain more what you exactly trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Rikesh I want to update word table, and set `Coefficient of variation` for each word (To simplify I used Select rather than update)

Comment: Some Confuse explain clearly

Comment: @Sathish Thanks for your attention, I try to execute first query but I can't!, second query have correct result but just for one id!

Comment: create your word table in sql fiddle then i will check the first query

Comment: Thanks again,I'm sorry! I forgot that, word table created

Answer (score 0):

your join syntax is wrong. as Jens said we cannot refer the outer table into inner sql. you can select like the following

```
select * from word,(
SELECT sqrt(variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)))/avg(ifnull(re_freq,0)) cv
FROM pre_cat 
left join (select goal.* from goal join word on goal.wordid= word.id)g on pre_cat.id= g.catid) gg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but it return wrong `Coefficient of variation`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from word join
(SELECT sqrt(variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)))/avg(ifnull(re_freq,0)) cv,
       g.wordid
FROM pre_cat 
left join goal g on pre_cat.id= g.catid
group by g.catid) gg on gg.wordid= word.id
```

Just join the word table with the subquery by wordid

Comment: tanks for you answer but this query return `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT sqrt(variance(ifnull(re_freq,0)))/avg(ifnull(re_freq,0)) cv, g.wor' at line 2`

Comment: updated. but unfortunately I don't have a way to check. I don't have the tables etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, It is a big database!! Thanks again, but your query return just one row.

Comment: updated once more. You can try to make sqlfiddle and post in the question

Comment: Thanks, It's return wrong `Coefficient of variation`, I add schema in sql fiddle but I don't know how can import a file

Comment: edited the answer once more. the fiddle is empty so there is no syntax errors but result is 0 rows

Comment: Thanks, It returns too many record for one id and each record have wrong `Coefficient of variation`

Comment: Looks like you miss some relation between wordid and catid.

Comment: I'm sorry for delay, I update sql fiddle link again.